# Xamarin Forms Android - "Resource is not available in the current context"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

When trying to debug my xamarin forms android application, in my MainActivity.cs file I get this error:

```
CS0103  The name "Resource" not found in the current context D:\MyApp\App\App.Android\MainActivity.cs   12
```

The code that belongs to this is the following:

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

When I comment out these lines, it compiles but each page has the title on like half the height of the page instead of inside the title bar. How can I fix this?

Comment: `clean` the project and `rebuild` it again It work. and if this is not work then remove `bin` and `obj` folder from your project and `rebuild` it again.

Comment: @Ironman tried that multiple times, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Add a diagnostic build output:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

And you could refer to :

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5261/the-name-resource-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score 0):

Either your project namespace ends with .Android or your namespace is not set the same as it is set in your project settings.

In case you have a namespace like MyApp.Android you should change it to MyApp.Droid.